# α-β prune algorithm - what should be the perfect leaf nodes order, which alpha-beta algorithm prunes as many nodes as possible?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm just start learning AI algorithms. when it comes across the α-β prune, this algorithm's performance is highly rely on the order of leaf nodes. But according to the textbook, this ordering function is not existing. Based on my research, it appears this issue is related with the even/odd number of leaf nodes, and the depth of the tree. Is this correct? For instance, given a binary tree with depth 4, and 0-15 for the value of leaf nodes, what should be a good ordering of the nodes, so that the algorithm can have maximum performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get maximum performance (=pruning) when the first leaf you get to has the best score.  Of course, if you knew which leaf had the best score there'd be no need to do alpha-beta.  So it's pretty much a catch-22.  In practice, you want to order the immediate children of a node during the search in decreasing estimated score order, where your estimates are the best guess you can come up with without actually performing a search.